# tb_blog main area left padding

Tags: theming

I'm using tb_blog theme for my website, demo site:
http://demo.themebrain.com/#blog

I want to remove the padding from left side of page without corrupting whole structure of website, I'm terrible with HTML and CSS stuff. 
I want a full page expanded blog.

Also I'm open to suggestions, including totally changing my blog theme to something new which by default have a full page blog theme and it's easy to customize or tell me which CSS files to fix in tb_blog theme to make it full page blog.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That theme is using a grid, looks like a base of 24. It's not the padding that's causing the blog to not display in the full page, but the grid (IE, the grid widths).

If your uncomfortable with updating the css of this theme, you may want to switch to a theme that's not grid based. Though it's not full page, [business](https://www.drupal.org/project/business) or something like it might be more suited to what you want to do.